# How to use favloader.js correctly?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to use [favloader.js](https://github.com/jcubic/favloader). Unfortunately, it does not work.

This was my try:

```js
favloader.init({
  gif: 'https://gifimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/favicon-gif-2.gif'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/favloader"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/favloader@0.x.x/parseGIF.js"></script>
```

Is there something wrong?

Would be thankful for help!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are running the script before the library is done loading. Try to add a "defer" attribute in your script tag.

`<script defer src="..."></script>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still does not work. :(